# Storing and playing JS generated audio in an <audio> tag without recording

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm messing around with Web Audio API trying to read out and play morse code but can't figure out if I'm missing something.

```js
const dest = ctx.createMediaStreamDestination();
const recorder = new MediaRecorder(dest.stream);
const morseArr = morse.split(' / ');
let t = ctx.currentTime;

const oscillator = ctx.createOscillator();
oscillator.type = "sine";
oscillator.frequency.value = 600;

const gainNode = ctx.createGain();
gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(0, t);
morseArr.forEach(word => {
  for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    switch (word[i]) {
      case ' ':
        t += unitLength * letterUnits;
        break;
      case '.':
        gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(1, t);
        t += unitLength * dotUnits;
        gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(0, t);
        break;
      case '-':
        gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(1, t);
        t += unitLength * dashUnits;
        gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(0, t);
        break;
    }     
    if (word[i] !== ' ' && word[i+1] && word[i+1] !== ' ') {
      t += unitLength * innerUnits;
    }
  }
  t += unitLength * wordUnits;
});
oscillator.connect(gainNode).connect(dest);
recorder.start(1);
oscillator.start();
oscillator.stop(t);

const chunks = [];
recorder.ondataavailable = (evt) => {
  // Push each chunk (blobs) in an array
  chunks.push(evt.data);
  if (ctx.currentTime >= t) {
    recorder.stop();
  }
};

recorder.onstop = (evt) => {
  // Make blob out of our blobs, and open it.
  const blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: "audio/ogg; codecs=opus" });
  document.querySelector("audio").src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
};
```

I've already looked at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60378168) but it's not exactly what I want. Using MediaRecorder means the full audio has to play and be recorded before it can be played back again.

So is there any way to generate this audio and store it without having it play out in full?